# White page react-router-dom

Tags: react-router-dom

I'm having a problem using the Router components with history prop on my react app, Whenever i want to move between pages i have a white page.
Route it's supposed to listen to my history changes

```
<Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
          <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
          <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Nope, there's no errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<Router history={history}>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/signin" component={<SignIn />} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={<SignUp />} />
            <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).